# Getting requests only in one computer in UmbracoApi

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, umbraco, umbraco7, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a Umbraco API project that using the UmbracoCms library V 7.15.3. The project work properly, but from some reason after that i copy the project to another computer. The API stop to work there and requests did not comes to the controller.

Is there a reason for something like this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco gives you a web application which you need to install and setup somewhere before it will work.

You probably used their installer initially which created an IIS website and a database for you. You don't need to re-run the installer, but you do need to copy the database and all the files and re-create the website in IIS on the other computer.

Simply moving files around is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for your quickly response. am not sure if i got you. but am talking about a local project that run via Visual Studio. so am not understand way i need IIS in this part? and also, i have an access to the db from the second computer to. but anyway i gees it's not the issue cause the requests did not even comes to the API.